# Programmatically Restart Service Fabric nodes with c#/rest api

Tags: c#, azure-service-fabric

Is there a way through which we can programmatically restart services fabric nodes with c#.

I am going through this docs= https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/servicefabric/sfclient-api-restartnode, but it does not specify anything about the authorization required.

Answer (score 0):

A Service Fabric cluster can be secured using X.509 certificates, Kerberos, or a combination of X.509 certificates and Kerberos.

To call the REST API, refer to:

- [How to Use REST APIs with X.509](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/servicefabric/v72/sfclient-v72-authenticating-service-fabric-rest-requests#how-to-use-rest-apis-with-x509)
- [How to Use the REST APIs with Kerberos](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/servicefabric/v72/sfclient-v72-authenticating-service-fabric-rest-requests#how-to-use-the-rest-apis-with-kerberos)

Answer (score -1):

In SF, two [roles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-cluster-security-roles) exist: Administrator and User.

> Administrators have full access to management capabilities (including
> read/write capabilities). By default, users only have read access to
> management capabilities (for example, query capabilities), and the
> ability to resolve applications and services.

So, if you are using the management endpoint as an admin you are good to go:

> The administrator access control type has full access to all the
> FabricClient APIs. It can perform any reads and writes on the Service
> Fabric cluster, including the following operations:

[..]

> **Cluster operations**
>
> NodeControl: starting, stopping, and restarting nodes